# stability analysis using spike and slab package in R software

Tags: r

I tried to use the `spikeslab` pacakges on my data set. when i try to run a stability analysis (based on ishwaran & rao article)
i get an error that i couldn't find anything helpful about it on internet.
my code is :

```
y <- diabet[, 1]
x<- diabet[, -1]
cv.obj <- cv.spikeslab(x = x, y = y, K = 20 )
```

first an second lines run without any problem but running line 3 is where i get this error message :

> "Error in svdwrapper(X) : svd(x) and svd(t(x)) both failed"

Please enlighten me about the cause and any possible way to resolve it.

> structure(list(location = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>   3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>   3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>   3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), sex = c(1L, 2L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L), age = c(37L, 37L, 39L, 32L, 34L, 28L, 25L, NA, 45L, 
>   50L, 38L, NA, NA, 62L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 57L, 40L, 51L, 
>   40L, 32L, 43L, 74L, 16L, 51L, 54L, 40L, 43L, 44L, 21L, 37L, 34L, 
>   62L, 33L, 47L, 63L, 42L, 32L, 52L, 48L, 62L, 45L, 59L, 40L, 41L, 
>   44L, 55L, 51L, 51L, 45L, 39L, 60L, 65L, 35L, 34L, 55L, 55L, 58L, 
>   67L, 25L, 43L, 50L, 51L, 54L, 65L, 53L, 52L, 62L, 48L, 50L, 64L, 
>   54L, 58L, 52L, 77L, 53L, 40L, 30L, 27L, 67L, 50L, 45L, 70L, 69L, 
>   61L, 57L, 61L, 54L, 65L, 75L, 62L, 78L, 56L, 58L, 55L, 60L, 60L, 
>   33L, 75L, 66L, 71L, 84L, 63L, 62L, 58L, 40L, 50L, 60L, 57L, 37L, 
>   38L, 51L, 60L, 45L, 50L, 17L, 14L, 22L, 35L, 50L, 63L, 38L, 45L, 
>   43L, 65L, 47L, 50L, 50L, 45L, 60L, 37L, 42L, 35L, 55L, 67L, 55L, 
>   49L, 52L, 58L, 70L, 62L, 30L, 45L, 50L, 45L, 60L, 50L, 29L, 60L, 
>   17L, 56L, 60L, 50L, 40L, 50L, 75L, 60L, 50L, 45L, 70L, 60L, 45L, 
>   40L, 45L, 28L, 70L, 49L, 50L, 60L, 34L, 35L, 55L, 52L, 50L, 53L, 
>   30L, 38L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 22L, 50L, 37L, 49L, 49L, 50L, 52L, 50L, 
>   25L, 45L, 40L, 45L, 60L, 40L, 50L, 32L, 55L, 38L, 70L, 95L, 50L, 
>   30L, 55L, 36L, 40L, 45L, 75L, 50L, NA, 70L, 32L, NA, 55L, 60L, 
>   39L, 60L, 70L, 47L, 60L, 59L, 30L, 60L, 45L, 38L, 70L, 40L, 23L, 
>   55L, 45L, 36L, 38L, 30L, 40L, 45L, 50L, 45L, 45L, 50L, 55L, 45L, 
>   50L, 50L, 37L, 45L, 78L, 45L, 60L, 70L, 37L, 58L, 60L, 50L, 35L, 
>   53L, 80L, 50L, 50L, 26L, 68L, 40L, 70L, 38L, 28L, 55L, 37L, 17L, 
>   45L, 55L, 36L, 48L, 60L, 40L, 55L, 65L, 60L, 66L, 53L, 69L, 55L, 
>   29L, 21L, 26L, 27L, 45L, 49L, 47L, 31L, 50L, 14L, 50L, 48L, 60L, 
>   49L, 55L, 70L, 22L, 70L, 36L, 60L, 45L, 42L, 60L, 30L, 50L, 55L, 
>   45L, 55L, 90L, 23L, 58L, 50L, 26L, 14L, 56L, 30L, 50L, 50L, 56L, 
>   60L, 32L, 52L, 40L, 36L, 61L, 19L, 28L, 32L, 51L, 21L, 50L, 44L, 
>   46L, 83L, 36L, 30L, 32L, 55L, 73L, 31L, 34L, 35L, 55L, 45L, 13L, 
>   37L, 45L, 25L, 21L, 26L, 60L, 45L, 50L, 22L, 51L, 80L, 43L, 80L, 
>   37L, 50L, 49L, 61L, 78L, 24L, 37L, 50L, 29L, 28L, 45L, 66L, 46L, 
>   58L, 84L, 31L, 70L, 22L, 27L, 35L, 81L, 34L, 17L, 29L, 28L, 21L, 
>   31L, 33L, 34L, 60L, 48L, 75L, 52L, 38L, 46L, 41L, 62L, 45L, 73L, 
>   43L, 53L, 44L, 31L, 52L, 28L, 53L, 50L, 70L, 44L, 40L, 56L, 54L, 
>   43L, 28L, 75L, 70L, 37L, 40L, 42L, 19L, 39L, 70L, 59L, 33L, 29L, 
>   25L, 35L, 48L, 44L, 36L, 31L, 35L, 35L, NA, 26L, 32L, 42L, 23L, 
>   25L, 48L, 40L, 45L, 34L, 57L, 29L, 53L, 27L, 17L, 21L, 57L, 24L, 
>   31L, 31L, 38L, 38L, 71L, 42L, 28L, 50L, 50L, 51L, 44L, 52L, 59L, 
>   63L, 40L, 20L, 56L, 45L, 65L, 60L, 37L, 70L, 34L, 55L, 63L, 43L, 
>   77L, 42L, 45L, 63L, 55L, 32L, 28L, 27L, 63L, 80L, 60L, 58L, 53L, 
>   42L, 43L, 43L, 56L, 28L, 31L, 29L, 59L, 33L), height1 = c(170L, 
>   147L, 160L, NA, 164L, 174L, 172L, 157L, 98L, 163L, 165L, 165L, 
>   175L, 171L, 175L, NA, 165L, 165L, 176L, 176L, 161L, 156L, 176L, 
>   165L, 165L, 175L, 162L, 155L, 165L, 160L, 175L, 184L, 174L, 166L, 
>   150L, 190L, 170L, 169L, 162L, 161L, 181L, 178L, 169L, 165L, 171L, 
>   165L, 162L, 172L, 170L, 170L, 165L, 163L, 175L, 167L, 165L, 179L, 
>   160L, 168L, 161L, 162L, 173L, 165L, 175L, 175L, 160L, 170L, 178L, 
>   170L, 171L, 170L, NA, 165L, NA, 165L, NA, 16L, 160L, 165L, 180L, 
>   176L, 165L, NA, NA, 180L, 170L, 170L, 170L, 115L, 165L, 165L, 
>   164L, 177L, 165L, 165L, 170L, 165L, 187L, NA, 185L, 175L, 160L, 
>   169L, 170L, 170L, NA, 176L, 170L, NA, 170L, 152L, 148L, 169L, 
>   170L, 187L, 159L, 161L, 151L, 159L, 154L, 160L, 149L, 152L, 158L, 
>   155L, 163L, 168L, 163L, 162L, 151L, 167L, 154L, 150L, 151L, 155L, 
>   159L, 160L, 153L, 160L, 141L, 161L, 146L, 159L, 149L, 150L, 145L, 
>   162L, 179L, 152L, 151L, 152L, 150L, 153L, 152L, 156L, 153L, 151L, 
>   159L, 160L, 165L, 160L, 155L, 148L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 158L, 156L, 
>   153L, 188L, 157L, 158L, 152L, 157L, 154L, 159L, 148L, 161L, 153L, 
>   146L, 175L, 156L, 153L, 149L, 153L, 162L, 158L, 159L, 159L, 158L, 
>   146L, 185L, 156L, 155L, 148L, 158L, 146L, 153L, 154L, 147L, 156L, 
>   149L, 174L, 158L, 151L, 150L, 157L, 145L, 151L, 162L, 157L, 155L, 
>   153L, 171L, 142L, 161L, 152L, 154L, 157L, 153L, 153L, 149L, 164L, 
>   145L, 162L, 180L, 152L, 162L, 162L, 150L, 149L, 153L, 151L, 155L, 
>   168L, 160L, 173L, 155L, 155L, 160L, 151L, 146L, 159L, 162L, 148L, 
>   158L, 157L, 167L, 152L, 151L, 156L, 156L, 152L, 158L, 156L, 168L, 
>   147L, 158L, 158L, 160L, 152L, 152L, 164L, 165L, 159L, 154L, 154L, 
>   145L, 164L, 163L, 152L, 156L, 159L, 155L, NA, 156L, 162L, 160L, 
>   154L, 152L, 163L, 154L, 165L, 153L, 152L, 146L, 157L, 156L, 164L, 
>   154L, 152L, 170L, 160L, 144L, 160L, 155L, 150L, 154L, 158L, 148L, 
>   155L, 150L, 179L, 156L, 164L, 152L, 151L, 161L, 160L, 160L, 155L, 
>   149L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 160L, 163L, 160L, 157L, 151L, 162L, 158L, 
>   152L, 155L, 166L, 159L, 160L, 158L, 150L, 158L, 158L, 154L, 152L, 
>   160L, 156L, 157L, 185L, 146L, 169L, 79L, 174L, 150L, 175L, 155L, 
>   163L, 155L, 153L, 190L, 135L, 159L, 158L, 164L, 153L, 157L, 150L, 
>   160L, 174L, 154L, 172L, 167L, 175L, 155L, 164L, 163L, 155L, 164L, 
>   144L, 161L, 178L, NA, 176L, 174L, 173L, 169L, 181L, 160L, 160L, 
>   145L, 165L, NA, 156L, NA, 171L, 157L, 140L, 160L, 150L, 170L, 
>   NA, 178L, 180L, 170L, NA, 167L, 175L, 171L, 187L, 178L, 170L, 
>   157L, 170L, 146L, 170L, 170L, 152L, 163L, 158L, 162L, 161L, NA, 
>   150L, 151L, 147L, 173L, 168L, 151L, 164L, 165L, 153L, 155L, 162L, 
>   169L, 150L, 144L, 168L, 152L, 164L, 183L, 161L, 170L, 157L, 155L, 
>   178L, 170L, 162L, 168L, 154L, 175L, 175L, 160L, 168L, 168L, 186L, 
>   150L, NA, 150L, 158L, 170L, 182L, 151L, 162L, 152L, 154L, 151L, 
>   160L, 154L, 154L, 160L, 155L, 170L, 160L, 154L, 180L, 173L, 177L, 
>   182L, 155L, 168L, 178L, 165L, 178L, 162L, 188L, 172L, 171L, 185L, 
>   185L, 172L, 175L, 157L, 165L, NA, 167L, 165L, 161L, 152L, 159L, 
>   175L, 176L, 164L, 175L, 168L, NA, 170L, 172L, 186L, 176L, 172L, 
>   181L, 182L, 165L), weight = c(120, 66, 72, NA, 84, 90, 72, 58, 
>   65, 80, 65, 115, 76, 84, 70, NA, 65, 76.5, 90, 80, 88, 50, 85, 
>   75, 68, 75, 85, 55, 73, 90, 82, 85, 83, 73, 58, 89, 75, 71, 75, 
>   65, 92, 82, 65, 75, 70, 82, 80, 68, 61, 100, 89, 85, 70, 87, 
>   68, 80, 67, 63, 63, 62, 53, 65, 68, 93, 74, 82, 91, 65, 74, 73, 
>   50, 105, NA, 70, NA, 63, 55, 84, 82, 89, 49, NA, NA, 73, 95, 
>   50, 52, 60, 75, 60, 70, 65, 52, 60, 50, 72, 95, 90, 85, 78, 50, 
>   93, 60, 60, 82, 70, 59, NA, 65, 85, 58, 68, 71, 98, 80, 69, 64, 
>   58, 59, 61, 45, 40, 57, 70, 63, 65.5, 65, 66, 63, 71, 69, 65, 
>   71, 66, 81, 52, 75, 73, 52, 64, 71, 65, 72, 66, 74, 76, 72, 74, 
>   52, 59, 68, 66, 59, 38, 64, 60, 72, 47, 72, 35, 75, 56, 72, 65, 
>   68, 82, 66, 76, 83, 68, 69, 66, 69, 74, 81, 70, 78, 56, 55, 95, 
>   95, 68, 70, 67, 70, 70, 69, 75, 70, 70, 71, 62, 60, 69, 95, 59, 
>   75, 91, 62, 79, 65, 90, 69, 55, 70, 55, 65, 55, 76, 76, 55, 74, 
>   65, 45, 45, 50, 63, 49, 71, 60, 60, 53, 51, 65, 72, 65, 74, 58, 
>   65, 71, 65, 88, 45, 89, 41, 61, 60, 68, 67, 69, 54, 73, 51, 59.9, 
>   89, 45, 60, 48, 49.5, 46.5, 57, 68, 66, 92, 68, 43, 63, 85, 53, 
>   53, 38, 66, 67, 59, 66, 54, 72, 66.4, 79, 44, 74, 84, 68, 73, 
>   73, 57.4, 44, 64, 62, 74, 62.6, 74, 46, 68, 55, 67, 55, 74.5, 
>   65, 61.5, 53, 80, 27, 54, 84, 37.5, 58.1, 54, 70, 63, 61, 85, 
>   79, 70.8, 54, 68, 80.8, 62, 67, 55, 93, 54, 80, 67.8, 75.3, 84, 
>   47, NA, 50, 65, 50, 49, NA, 65, 52, 58, 58, 59, 46, 73, 60, 59, 
>   51, 57, 76.5, 76, 38, 78, 159, 82, 78, 77, 56, 83.2, 85, 104, 
>   80, 39, 86, 73, 64, 51, 62, 54, 61, 63, 48, 81, 42, 75.5, 49, 
>   67, 90, 60, 59, 55, 54, 99, NA, 110, 58, 70, 60, 93, 60.5, 64.5, 
>   55, 51, 58, 63, NA, 72, 74, 48, 79, 54.5, 66, NA, 75, 89, 89, 
>   78, 70.5, 76, 77, 99.5, 82, 99, 54, 59, 55, 85, 73, 70, 63, 75, 
>   68, 66.5, NA, 85, 77, 78, 68, 83, 65, 55, 80, 71, 96, 89, 57, 
>   90, 59, 67, 59, 60, 62, 70, 79, 72, 64, 65, 60, 71, 70, 57, 79, 
>   91, 50, 74.5, 66, 91, 44, NA, 50, 53, 68, 95, 51, 78, 57.5, 40, 
>   70.5, 60, 74, 70, 82, 90, 94, 72, 57.5, 91, 86, 68, 77, 51, 83, 
>   73, 76, 68, 65, 91, 77, 965, 99, 96, 80, 82, 57, 82, NA, 60, 
>   69, 67, 65, 57, 63, 60, 68, 62, 64, NA, 95, 60, 77, 104, 76, 
>   83, 80, 74), BMI = c(38, 30, 28, NA, 31, 30, 24, 24, NA, 30, 
>   24, 42, 25, 28, 23, NA, 24, 28, 29, 26, 34, 21, 27, 28, 24, 24, 
>   32, 23, 27, 35, 27, 25, 27, 26, 26, 24, 26, 25, 29, 25, 28, 26, 
>   23, 28, 24, 30, 30, 23, 22, 35, 33, 32, 23, 31, 25, 25, 26, 22, 
>   25, 24, 18, 24, 22, 30, 29, 28, 29, 22, 24, 25, NA, 39, NA, 26, 
>   NA, 25, 21, 31, 25, 23, 18, NA, NA, 23, 33, 17, 18, 45, 26, 22, 
>   26, 21, 19, 22, 17, 26, 27, NA, 25, 25, 20, 32, 21, 21, NA, 23, 
>   24, NA, 22, 26, 26, 23, 24, 28, 31, 26, 28, 22, 22, 23, 20, 17, 
>   22, 29, 23, 23, 24, 35, 27, 25, 29, 28, 31, 27, 31, 21, 32, 28, 
>   26, 24, 30, 25, 32, 29, 35, 29, 22, 32, NA, 25, 30, 28, 24, 16, 
>   27, 26, 28, 18, 26, 14, 31, 25, 28, 25, 26, 32, 27, 32, 24, 27, 
>   27, 28, 25, 31, 32, 31, 30, 23, 23, 30, 39, 29, 31, 28, 26, 28, 
>   27, 30, 28, 30, 21, 25, 25, 31, 38, 25, 32, 38, 28, 32, 28, 30, 
>   27, 24, 31, 22, 31, 24, 28, 30, 22, 31, 22, 22, 17, 21, 26, 19, 
>   30, 25, 27, 19, 24, 24, 22, 28, 28, 22, 28, 31, 27, 38, 18, 31, 
>   18, 20, 25, 28, 26, 30, 25, 29, 19, 27, 36, 18, 21, 21, 22, 19, 
>   23, 29, 26, 38, 24, 20, 25, 33, 21, 23, 16, 25, 25, 23, 28, 23, 
>   26, 25, 30, 19, 30, 33, 28, NA, 30, 22, 17, 27, 27, 28, 26, 27, 
>   20, 29, 20, 27, 20, 25, 27, 27, 18.5, 31, 12, 21, 35, 17, 24, 
>   22, 32, 26, 27, 27, 32, 26, 23, 30, 31, 24, 26, 23, 43, 22, 33, 
>   27, 29, 32, 18, NA, 22, 25, 20, 21, NA, 24, 21, 23, 23, 26, 18, 
>   29, 25, 26, 20, 23, 31, 21, 18, 27, 31, 27, 35, 25, 23, 31, 35, 
>   44, 22, 21, 15, 29, 24, 22, 25, 24, 24, 21, 20, 27, 15, 25, 20, 
>   25, 34, 25, 22, 27, 21, 31, NA, 36, 19, 23, 21, 28, 24, 25, 26, 
>   NA, NA, 29, NA, 25, 30, 24, 31, 24, 23, NA, 24, 27, 31, NA, 25, 
>   25, 26, 28, 26, 34, 22, 20, 26, 29, 25, 30, 24, 30, 26, 26, NA, 
>   38, 34, 36, 23, 29, 29, 20, 29, 30, 40, 34, 20, 44, 27, 24, 26, 
>   NA, 19, 22, 27, 29, 27, 21, 21, 13, 25, 24, 26, 30, 20, 27, 23, 
>   26, 20, NA, 22, 21, 24, 29, 23, 30, 25, 17, 31, 23, 31, 30, 32, 
>   30, 33, 28, 24, 28, 29, 22, 23, 22, 29, 23, 28, 21, 24, 26, 26, 
>   22, 29, 28, 27, 27, 23, 30, NA, 22, 25, 26, 21, 23, 21, 19, 25, 
>   20, 23, NA, 33, 20, 22, 34, 26, 25, 24, 27), f.sistol = c(150L, 
>   130L, 110L, 120L, 110L, 110L, 130L, 120L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 140L, 
>   140L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 110L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 180L, 
>   110L, 100L, 120L, 120L, 100L, 130L, 130L, 120L, 150L, 120L, 110L, 
>   130L, 110L, 110L, 130L, 120L, 160L, 140L, 150L, 16L, 120L, 120L, 
>   120L, 11L, 130L, 120L, 90L, 120L, 190L, 140L, 120L, 120L, 150L, 
>   150L, 100L, 140L, 120L, 100L, 120L, 150L, 120L, 170L, 110L, 160L, 
>   120L, 120L, 100L, 120L, 140L, 90L, 120L, 170L, 100L, 120L, 110L, 
>   140L, 120L, 165L, 90L, 100L, 140L, 150L, 160L, 140L, 140L, 180L, 
>   100L, 120L, 150L, 120L, 100L, 100L, 150L, 100L, 140L, 120L, 140L, 
>   140L, 100L, 120L, 140L, 150L, 110L, 100L, 120L, 120L, 130L, 170L, 
>   70L, 130L, 120L, 80L, 110L, 110L, 90L, 100L, 100L, 70L, 80L, 
>   100L, 120L, 120L, 90L, 90L, 110L, 110L, 100L, 180L, 130L, 90L, 
>   160L, 90L, 110L, 140L, 130L, 80L, 100L, 90L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 
>   80L, 80L, 110L, 110L, 90L, 120L, 80L, 120L, 100L, 60L, 130L, 
>   110L, 110L, 110L, 80L, 130L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 110L, 120L, 
>   110L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 140L, 120L, 120L, 100L, 140L, 110L, 110L, 
>   110L, 110L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 110L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 100L, 100L, 
>   100L, 140L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 120L, 90L, 130L, 110L, 100L, 
>   100L, 110L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 110L, 90L, 120L, 110L, 130L, 90L, 
>   100L, 130L, 100L, 140L, 110L, 110L, 120L, 90L, 90L, 120L, 100L, 
>   110L, 120L, 110L, 110L, 150L, 140L, 110L, 90L, 110L, 80L, 130L, 
>   100L, 110L, 80L, 110L, 90L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 
>   90L, 130L, 110L, 120L, 90L, 130L, 100L, 100L, 140L, 130L, 140L, 
>   100L, 100L, 90L, 120L, 110L, 130L, 90L, 90L, 120L, 90L, 100L, 
>   80L, NA, 100L, 110L, 100L, 90L, 90L, 90L, 100L, 130L, 100L, 90L, 
>   100L, 140L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 12L, 
>   100L, 140L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 90L, 90L, 80L, 80L, 100L, 90L, 
>   100L, 90L, 110L, 80L, 90L, 90L, 100L, 110L, 110L, 120L, 130L, 
>   100L, 110L, 110L, 140L, 90L, 100L, 90L, 100L, 70L, 80L, 80L, 
>   80L, 120L, 110L, 90L, 120L, 110L, 140L, 90L, 110L, 110L, 100L, 
>   100L, 100L, 110L, 120L, 90L, 110L, 90L, 90L, 100L, 120L, 110L, 
>   90L, 90L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 100L, 90L, 90L, 130L, 
>   90L, 140L, 110L, 110L, 135L, 115L, 130L, 110L, 110L, 130L, 185L, 
>   135L, 110L, 120L, 100L, 130L, 110L, 130L, 120L, 130L, 110L, 135L, 
>   110L, 120L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 140L, 100L, 90L, 100L, 90L, 90L, 
>   120L, 100L, 130L, 16L, 100L, 120L, 165L, 145L, 135L, 120L, 150L, 
>   100L, 110L, 100L, 130L, 100L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 130L, 110L, 140L, 
>   130L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 120L, 100L, 13L, 120L, 110L, 120L, 100L, 
>   100L, 120L, 140L, 120L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 110L, 100L, 100L, 110L, 
>   125L, 110L, 130L, 90L, 110L, 125L, 120L, 110L, 135L, 125L, 125L, 
>   110L, 100L, 110L, 90L, 100L, 120L, 100L, 100L, 90L, 100L, 100L, 
>   100L, 110L, 110L, 110L, 130L, 110L, 110L, 80L, 140L, 100L, NA, 
>   140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 100L, 145L, 165L, 140L, 155L, 145L, 
>   210L, 180L, 150L, 175L, 175L, 100L, 145L, 140L, 110L, 110L, 100L, 
>   140L, 155L, 180L, 150L, 130L, 100L, 130L, 110L, 130L, 105L, 130L, 
>   125L, 150L, 115L), f.diastol = c(90, 70, 60, 70, 70, 80, 80, 
>   70, 70, 80, 80, 90, 20, 70, 80, 90, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 
>   70, 60, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 90, 80, 80, 90, 70, 70, 80, 80, 
>   10, 90, 90, 90, 80, 80, 80, 70, 90, 80, 80, 80, 80, 90, 90, 80, 
>   80, 50, 70, 80, 80, 80, 80, 90, 80, 80, 70, 80, 80, 90, 70, 80, 
>   70, 60, 80, 90, 60, 80, 80, 80, 70, 49, 70, 70, 80, 90, 60, 60, 
>   60, 80, 60, 70, 90, 70, 60, 70, 80, 60, 80, 70, 70, 70, 70, 80, 
>   90, 80, 80, 70, 70, 80, 60, 80, 60, 70, 60, 60, 80, 80, 60, 60, 
>   80, 60, 60, 60, 80, 70, 80, 60, 80, 60, 70, 80, 70, 80, 80, 60, 
>   60, 80, 80, 50, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 60, 60, 60, 80, 80, 80, 60, 
>   80, 80, 80, 100, 60, 60, 70, 60, 60, 80, 80, 80, 60, 90, 60, 
>   60, 60, 60, 50, 80, 50, 80, 80, 80, 40, 80, 60, 90, 70, 60, 60, 
>   90, 60, 60, 80, 80, 60, 80, 80, 70, 60, 80, 80, 80, 60, 80, 60, 
>   90, 50, 50, 70, 60, 80, 80, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 80, 10, 70, 60, 
>   60, 61, 60, 20, 80, 80, 80, 70, 60, 60, 60, 40, 80, 90, 60, 60, 
>   60, 80, 80, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 40, 60, 60, 60, 80, 60, 
>   60, 60, 80, 80, 80, 80, 60, 70, 60, 80, 60, 60, 60, 80, 60, 60, 
>   80, 60, 60, 60, NA, 60, 70, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 40, 60, 60, 
>   80, 70, 60, 60, 60, 80, 60, 60, 60, 80, 60, 80, 60, 60, 60, 60, 
>   60, 60, 60, 60, 40, 70, 60, 70, 60, 60, 60, 60, 70, 60, 80, 80, 
>   60, 70, 70, 80, 60, 60, 60, 60, 40, 60, 60, 60, 60, 80, 60, 80, 
>   60, 80, 60, 80, 80, 70, 80, 60, 70, 80, 60, 80, 60, 60, 60, 80, 
>   70, 60, 60, 80, 70, 80, 80, 80, 70, 60, 50, 70, 60, 80, 80, 70, 
>   80, 75, 80, 75, 80, 80, 100, 80, 70, 80, 60, 80, 70, 70, 75, 
>   85, 70, 80, 70, 75, 80, 80, 80, 60, 60, 60, 80, 60, 60, 90, 80, 
>   70, 80, 80, 75, 85, 85, 85, 80, 95, 70, 70, 70, 80, 80, 80, 70, 
>   70, 70, 70, 90, 80, 70, 70, 80, 80, 70, 80, 80, 70, 80, 70, 70, 
>   70, 70, 80, 70, 70, 80, 70, 80, 80, 70, 75, 70, 75, 60, 80, 75, 
>   80, 60, 85, 75, 85, 90, 90, 80, 60, 50, 80, 60, 80, 60, 60, 80, 
>   80, 70, 70, 70, 80, 70, 70, 60, 85, 80, NA, 90, 90, 90, 95, 90, 
>   80, 95, 100, 90, 80, 90, 120, 95, 90, 90, 90, 80, 90, 90, 65, 
>   75, 70, 90, 90, 10, 90, 75, 80, 85, 70, 85, 75, 80, 80, 85, 75
>   ), sabeghe.feshar = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, NA, 2L, NA, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 
>   2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 
>   NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, 
>   NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 
>   1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), sabeghe.dyabet = c(2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
>   1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
>   NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 
>   2L, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
>   NA, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, NA, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, NA, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 1L, 2L), BS = c(115L, 129L, NA, 87L, 78L, 109L, 87L, 123L, 
>   98L, 118L, 81L, 99L, 96L, NA, 99L, 96L, 96L, 96L, 89L, 385L, 
>   85L, NA, 73L, 129L, NA, 130L, 118L, 158L, 217L, 118L, 117L, 95L, 
>   107L, 126L, 139L, 70L, 317L, 123L, 166L, 58L, 177L, 127L, 91L, 
>   313L, 117L, 123L, 112L, 122L, 133L, 153L, 138L, 165L, NA, 224L, 
>   118L, 340L, 120L, NA, 125L, 130L, 110L, 98L, NA, NA, 128L, 80L, 
>   170L, 251L, 89L, 134L, 84L, 80L, 108L, 173L, 107L, 107L, 138L, 
>   140L, 350L, 144L, NA, NA, 109L, NA, 110L, 123L, 235L, 115L, NA, 
>   125L, NA, 177L, 150L, NA, 114L, 208L, 122L, 278L, 110L, 128L, 
>   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 122L, 123L, 154L, NA, 
>   125L, 126L, 133L, 130L, 130L, 126L, 86L, 53L, 354L, 90L, NA, 
>   120L, 182L, 77L, 156L, 120L, 126L, 110L, 100L, 154L, 211L, NA, 
>   117L, 102L, 113L, 123L, 130L, 109L, 99L, 292L, 113L, 117L, NA, 
>   136L, 99L, 143L, 99L, 97L, 164L, 101L, 115L, 89L, 89L, NA, 120L, 
>   120L, 158L, 93L, 118L, 125L, 131L, 120L, 121L, 164L, NA, 121L, 
>   121L, 141L, 114L, 116L, 120L, 132L, 140L, 100L, 130L, 123L, 118L, 
>   251L, 126L, 144L, 103L, 105L, 113L, 74L, 162L, 91L, NA, 152L, 
>   11L, 115L, 152L, 142L, 152L, 116L, 110L, 118L, 110L, NA, 110L, 
>   124L, 98L, 71L, 123L, 118L, 106L, 112L, 416L, 109L, NA, 117L, 
>   92L, 114L, 56L, 99L, 106L, 130L, 130L, 94L, 114L, 282L, 96L, 
>   120L, 111L, 115L, 118L, 116L, 99L, 156L, 111L, 128L, 90L, NA, 
>   66L, 109L, 138L, 296L, 238L, 226L, 326L, 490L, 77L, 86L, NA, 
>   117L, 149L, 94L, 102L, 117L, 112L, 176L, 168L, 122L, 97L, 110L, 
>   114L, 94L, 93L, 103L, 100L, 73L, 172L, 91L, 102L, 103L, NA, 100L, 
>   119L, 123L, 87L, 113L, 153L, 109L, 143L, 107L, 104L, NA, 103L, 
>   112L, 106L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 102L, 87L, 111L, 99L, NA, 139L, 
>   100L, 106L, 109L, 186L, 83L, 102L, 107L, 82L, 99L, NA, 183L, 
>   107L, 49L, 218L, 116L, 122L, 104L, 114L, 106L, 81L, 96L, 131L, 
>   88L, 101L, 93L, 88L, 140L, 130L, 86L, 99L, 103L, 111L, 111L, 
>   125L, 104L, 106L, 94L, 91L, 104L, 94L, 84L, 103L, 378L, 193L, 
>   143L, 93L, 90L, 100L, 111L, 134L, 84L, 128L, 105L, 162L, NA, 
>   97L, 148L, 180L, 109L, 105L, 133L, 145L, 134L, 152L, 96L, 111L, 
>   141L, 121L, 87L, 100L, 357L, 215L, 111L, 184L, 108L, 120L, 164L, 
>   113L, 83L, 150L, 141L, 106L, 99L, 111L, 107L, 116L, 101L, 101L, 
>   117L, 170L, 92L, 97L, 94L, 83L, 97L, 81L, 102L, 106L, 109L, 87L, 
>   323L, 134L, 106L, 93L, 202L, 118L, 116L, 169L, 267L, 203L, NA, 
>   NA, 143L, NA, 295L, 126L, 184L, 180L, NA, NA, 510L, 106L, 53L, 
>   206L, 104L, 73L, 145L, 111L, NA, NA, NA, 128L, 110L, 97L, NA, 
>   NA, 135L, 115L, 140L, 137L, 117L, 167L, 122L, 100L, 125L, 98L, 
>   90L, 107L, 134L, 94L, 96L, 128L, 104L, 87L, 351L, 94L, 104L, 
>   95L, 113L, 84L, 114L, 98L, 86L, 105L, 98L, 128L, 94L, 207L, 202L, 
>   87L, NA, 500L, 129L, 297L, 63L, 99L, 89L, 128L, 165L, 90L, 80L, 
>   115L, 84L, 175L, 164L, 113L, 99L, 87L, 98L, 219L, 227L, 303L, 
>   427L, 101L, 73L, 87L, 136L, 112L, 279L, 150L, 247L, 447L, 352L, 
>   220L, 459L, 396L, 290L, 96L), obesity = c(1L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 
>   1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
>   1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, NA, 1L, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, 1L, 
>   0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
>   0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 
>   0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
>   0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>   1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>   0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
>   0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 
>   0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 
>   1L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 
>   1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
>   0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
>   0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)),

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When your question is about debugging code, we ask you to provide a fully reproducible example (especially within the `r` tag). For example, you may wish to include built-in or self-created data in the example within your question. This helps us to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks sir @hack-r

Comment: My dataset is consist of 8 variables and 1500 data. I would like to attach it here but is it possible ?

Comment: I will see if I can replicate the error using the built-in dataset `diabetesI`

Comment: I believe its not gonna work cause ishwaran & rao used that data in their article and had no problem. Can i email my data to you please?

Comment: You are correct. That is an important clue. That tells us that the problem has nothing to do with the code - it is to do with the data. Rather than emailing the data could you please copy and paste the results of this command into the bottom of your question? `dput(head(diabet, 500))` that will give us the first 500 lines of your data.

Comment: I know its a big favour but is it possible to look at my data sir?

Comment: i excluded last 3 lines that kinda identified as codes by the website.  these lines are .Names = c("location", 
"sex", "age", "height1", "weight", "BMI", "f.sistol", "f.diastol", 
"sabeghe.feshar", "sabeghe.dyabet", "BS", "obesity"), row.names = c(NA, 
500L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Thank you actually im looking forward to any suggestion from you and other experts